# Why is my text_area adding indentation when I use a line break? - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting a bug when I use a text_area in my rails app.  The box takes line breaks, and makes them indentation.  Here is a screen shot, any idea where these indentations are coming from?

https://files.getdropbox.com/u/312568/Picture%2031.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with some early versions of the haml plugin.  If you are saying:

```
= f.text_area :body
```

you might try

```
~ f.text_area :body
```

instead.  This invokes whitespace preservation, which is nice for user-entered text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try trimming your text using .strip

```
  str.strip => new_str

Returns a copy of str with leading and trailing whitespace removed.

   "    hello    ".strip   #=> "hello"
   "\tgoodbye\r\n".strip   #=> "goodbye"
```

If it doesn't work, I'll need more code to assist you